# how to execute some code after a post is published in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, posts, actions, publish

I have written a simple code to do something after a post is updated or published (its related to the varnish purge). I put my code inside post.php file. Everything was just fine before the latest update (4.8.3), after that all my codes were vanished!! of course it is a normal behavior because the post.php file has  been replaced with a new one from update patch. I want to know how can I execute some code after a post is updated or published and my codes do not disappear after a Wordpress update? I don't want to use plugins too :D. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `save_post` [action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post). This allows you to add a function when a post is saved (updated).

You can hook into it like this:

```
function your_save_post_function( $post_id ) {
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'your_save_post_function' );
```

Remember to not change WordPress Core files, as these will be overwritten when WordPress is updated. You can put this code in your `functions.php` file, or anywhere else in your theme folder.

Comment: You mean functions.php is not overwritten when the Wordpress is updated? I only have to insert my function and use `add action` to add my function and then save the file.  Is there anything else should I do to my function work?

Comment: Nothing in the `wp-content` folder will be overwritten when WordPress is updated, so you can safely add it to `wp-content/themes/your-themes/functions.php` file.

Comment: Thank you very much. Final question: if I want to pass arguments to my function I should use `add_action( 'save_post', 'your_save_post_function',10,2 );` for a function with two arguments. But how the function is called? for example my arguments are $postID, $status. I mean when the function is called how wordpress knows I need postID as the 1st argument and the $status which is a custom defined variable as the 2nd argument?

Comment: `save_post` fires even when a post is _unpublished_ (set back to draft).

Comment: I updated my answer. You should pass the `$post_id` to your function. You can check the codex page I linked for a further detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
add_action( 'save_post', 'varnish_purge' );
function varnish_purge()
{
 // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace publish_{post} , where {post} is any wordpress post type.

```
function post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
    $author = $post->post_author; /* Post author ID. */
    $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );
    $email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author );
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $permalink = get_permalink( $ID );
    $edit = get_edit_post_link( $ID, '' );
    $to[] = sprintf( '%s <%s>', $name, $email );
    $subject = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $title );
    $message = sprintf ('Congratulations, %s! Your article “%s” has been published.' . "\n\n", $name, $title );
    $message .= sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink );
    $headers[] = '';
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
```